# Xamarin forms application cannot be opened on smartphone

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I am developing a Xamarin forms application with a single page. When I try to install the application on Samsung Galaxy S7 it installed good, but the open option is disabled and it didn't created an icon in the list of applications. Even in the emulator the application is not showing up.

In the .Droid project this is my create.

```
 protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
 {
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

    LoadApplication (new App ());
 }
```

In the PCL project this is the constructor in my App class. And the scorePage is just a simple content page.

```
 public App ()
 {
     MainPage = new ScorePage();
 }
```

Comment: 1) Well for the logo you have to add it the drawabled inside Resources and refer to it in the manifest ( you can do that from the android project's property)  
 
2) What do you mean with Open options disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing app name in your launcher? Does it have `Label` Property specified in android project `MainActivity.cs` file? Make sure your don't remove it.